# Matching multiple values using ARRAY_CONTAINS in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hive

I can use `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function separately `ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, value1) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, value2)` to get the result. But I don't want to use `ARRAY_CONTAINS` multiple times. Is there a function to check both values presence at a time in an array.

** Updated from the comment **

Table contains: id, label, Array[type], Array[feature], textual1, numeric1 and numeric2 columns.

The query is: (

```
SELECT id, label, textual1 
FROM table  
WHERE 
           ARRAY_CONTAINS(type, 'productType1') 
      AND  ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature1') 
      AND  ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature2') AND  numeric1 > 3) 
UNION (
         SELECT id, label, textual1 
         FROM table  
         WHERE 
                   ARRAY_CONTAINS(type, 'productType1') 
              AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature1') 
              AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature3') 
              AND  numeric2 > 4
      ) 

ORDER BY label
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use ARRAY_CONTAINS multiple times?

Comment: I am using an inner join, so checking values separately may cause extra overhead.

Comment: It does not seem to make much sense. Please show your code (or simplification of it) and a small data sample

Comment: Table contains `id, label, Array[type], Array[feature], textual1, numeric1 and numeric2` columns. The query is  `(SELECT id, label, textual1 FROM table  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(type, 'productType1') AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature1') AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature2') AND  numeric1 > 3) UNION (SELECT id, label, textual1 FROM table  WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(type, 'productType1') AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature1') AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature, 'feature3') AND  numeric2 > 4) ORDER BY label`

Comment: Please move it to youe post

Comment: Is there a way I can find array intersection in Spark SQL. In hiveql `array_intersect(array1, array2)[0] is not null` can be used to find if there is any common element between the two arrays. What is the equivalent of it in Spark SQL?

Comment: I am not aware of built-in `array_intersect` on neither of them. There is however this set of UDF https://github.com/brndnmtthws/facebook-hive-udfs/tree/master/src/main/java/com/facebook/hive/udf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be written as following -

```
SELECT      id, label, textual1 

FROM        table 

WHERE       ARRAY_CONTAINS(type     ,'productType1') 
        AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature  ,'feature1') 

        AND (   
                (   ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature  ,'feature2') 
                AND numeric1 > 3
                )

            or  (   ARRAY_CONTAINS(feature  ,'feature3') 
                AND numeric2 > 4
                )
            )

ORDER BY    label
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.